# page always refreshing(the tag in the brower always show the active circle),is that because i use iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, getattribute

new occuring question:

the same code, but i have found every time, i refresh this page, the tag in the brower always show the active circle, what 's wrong with it,thanks!
i use iframe, but i search in the stackoverflow and there is similar question and he use js to generate the iframe, but i did so in the code below. i just did not success

old question solved:
my question is focused on the following there lines:

`textarea.style.color = '#C5C8C6';
//textarea.style.color = rightL.dataset.brown;`
//or even this did not work: textarea.style.color =  rightL.getAttribute('data-brown');`

when i use

```
`textarea.style.color = '#C5C8C6',
```

it works,but when i use html5 way:

```
//textarea.style.color = rightL.dataset.brown;`
```

it did not work,i do not know why, please help, thanks.And i am using crome brower.

All the code is above:

//HTML

```
        <div class="grid_section second_grid">
        <div class="tabs_section" >
            <ul class="tabs_section_main_header">
                <li class="component_tab active">{{'Untitled'}}</li>
                <li class="component_tab active rightL" data-white = 'rgb(157, 190, 140)'>乳白</li>
                <li class="component_tab active rightR" data-brown = '#C5C8C6'>舒棕</li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="tabs_section_main_content">
                <li class="component_tab_content">
                    <textarea id="textarea">@if(isset($code)) {{$code}} @endif</textarea>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//JS

```
(function(){


        //generate iframe using js before any js code      
        function createIframe(){
          var i = document.createElement("iframe");
          i.id = "iFrame";
          i.contentEditable = "true";
          document.getElementsByClassName("iframe")[0].appendChild(i); 
        };

        createIframe();


         //all the vars
         var iframeOuterDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('iframe')[0];
          var iFrame = document.getElementById("iFrame");
         var iframeContent = iFrame.contentWindow;
         var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

          var body = document.getElementsByClassName('playCode')[0];
         var playIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('play')[0];
         var editMode = document.getElementsByClassName('editMode')[0];
         var instantIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('instant')[0];
         var rightL = document.getElementsByClassName('rightL')[0];
         var rightR = document.getElementsByClassName('rightR')[0];



         //show html code
          runCode.count = 0;
          function runCode() {  

                   if(textarea.value=="" && runCode.count==0){  
                     iframeContent.document.writeln('请输入要运行的代码');  
                     runCode.count++;

                     return false;
                   }

                   iframeContent.document.open('text/html', 'replace');  
                   iframeContent.document.writeln(textarea.value);  
                   iframeContent.document.close();  


          }

          runCode();          


//addeventlistener code, first Check for browser support of event handling capability
function addEve(target,myAction){
   if (window.addEventListener){

                 if(myAction === 'mouseover'){

                       target.addEventListener(myAction, function(){
                          body.classList.add('action');
                      }, false);       

                 }else if(myAction === 'click'){

                      if(target === editMode){
                             editMode.addEventListener(myAction, function(e){
                              e.preventDefault();
                              body.classList.toggle('action');
                            },false);                        
                      }else if(target === playIcon){
                          playIcon.addEventListener(myAction, function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            runCode();

                          },false);                        
                      }else if(target === instantIcon){
                              instantIcon.addEventListener(myAction, function(e){
                              e.preventDefault();

                              textarea.addEventListener('input', function(){
                                  runCode();
                              });



                              },false);                         
                      }else if(target === rightR){



                                rightR.addEventListener(myAction, function(e){
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                  textarea.style.color = 'rgb(157, 190, 140)';
                               //textarea.style.color = rightL.dataset.white;`
                              //or even this did not work: textarea.style.color =  rightL.getAttribute('data-white');`
                                });





                       }else if(target === rightL){
                                 rightL.addEventListener(myAction, function(e){
                                  e.preventDefault();
                                  textarea.style.color = '#C5C8C6';
                                  // rightL.getAttribute('data-brown');
                                });                              
                       }


                    }









  }else if(window.attachEvent){

            if(myAction === 'mouseover'){

                     target.attachEvent('on' + myAction,  function(){
                          body.classList.add('action');
                      }, false); 

            }else if(myAction === 'click'){

                      playIcon.attachEvent('on' + myAction, function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        runCode();
                        //playIcon.style.color = 'red';
                      });
                      editMode.attachEvent('on' + myAction, function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        body.classList.toggle('action');
                      });            

            }

  }


}

addEve(editMode, 'click');
addEve(playIcon, 'click');
addEve(iFrame,'mouseover');
addEve(instantIcon, 'click');
addEve(rightL, 'click');
addEve(rightR, 'click');


           }());
```

Comment: btw, i am using laravel,so you can see {{}} in the code. besides, you can see the main code in the function addEve(target,myAction){...}

Comment: In the code you posted, `rightL` does not have a `data-brown` attribute. It does have a `data-white` attribute, though.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLNode list ... use rightL[0] to get the first (and only in your case) ... you can also use `rightL[0].dataset.brown` instead of `getAttribute`

Comment: 'var rightL = document.getElementsByClassName('rightL')[0];
 var rightR = document.getElementsByClassName('rightR')[0];'                         i use this in the code,so i directly use the rightL, is there anything i am missing? Thanks

Comment: what is the output of this line console.log(rightR.getAttribute('data-brown'));

Comment: i mix the classname,I should have make more clear for my class,thanks

Comment: and the tag in the brower always show the active circle, what 's wrong with it,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine.  The confusion seems to be around the naming of **rightL** and **rightR** and **data-white** and **data-brown**.  If you change rightL to rightR it worked for me.  So both these below work...

```
rightR.getAttribute('data-brown')
rightL.getAttribute('data-white')
```

Comment: yeah, the naming of the class issue,thanks. and do you know why the tag in the brower always show the active circle when i refresh this page？ thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by tag and active circle?

Comment: I donot know how to call it but it's just always show the refreshing status in the tag of the browser when my refreshing the page.

Comment: You mean the page doesn't stop loading?

Comment: yeah,kind of. when you refresh a page, there is a moving circle. I mean that. and even when the page finish showing all the stuff, the circle still keep moving circling

Comment: It means a resource on your page, an image or the iframe or something is still loading.  I created a test page on my desktop and it doesn't do this but I probably have a cut down version of your code.  You need to remove things one by one (e.g. the iframe) to isolate what is causing it then put them back and fix the issue.

Comment: Also try the Network tab in Chrome dev tools.  You may be able to see what resource is not loading.

Comment: seem not showing anything downloading. does the iframe  cause this cause when i delete the js code and it's normal again

Comment: I don't know sorry, I don't have enough information to reproduce your issue.  If you can add a link to a page that shows the problem that would help.